# Clipping lines within ellipse on javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, clipping

I am drawing a filled ellipse (using arc()) on the javascript canvas:

```
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, dotDiameter / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = color1;
ctx.fill();
```

I then want to draw a line, that is clipped to this ellipse, in a different color.

```
ctx.clip(); // Clip to the ellipse
ctx.strokeStyle = color2;
ctx.moveTo(centerX - dotRadius, centerY);
ctx.lineTo(centerX + dotRadius, centerY);
ctx.stroke();
```

However, the ellipse is also stroked with color2.

How can I clip lines to my ellipse, but not have the ellipse stroked? Is there a way to remove the ellipse (aka arc) from the canvas after I call clip()?

Thanks!

(FYI, this is an oversimplification of my code. The lines that stroked are more complicated than a single horizontal line and the lines do need to be clipped.)

Comment: a `ctx.arc(` is not going to draw an ellipse

Comment: @HelderSepulveda: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc about drawing circles (and portions of circles) using arc().

Comment: Hi Steve, yes but you said an ellipse... arc won't do ellipse

Answer (score 2):

We can calculate a point on the perimeter of an ellipsis with some basic trigonometry...

```
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  x += radiusX * Math.cos(lineangle)
  y += radiusY * Math.sin(lineangle)
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
```

See code snippet below, I'm drawing an ellipse and a line from center to edge.

```js
ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

function draw(x, y, radiusX, radiusY, lineangle, color1, color2) {
  if (color1) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.ellipse(x, y, radiusX, radiusY, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = color1;
    ctx.fill();
  }

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = color2;
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  x += radiusX * Math.cos(lineangle)
  y += radiusY * Math.sin(lineangle)
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

angle = 0

function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  draw(80, 80, 70, 50, angle, "red", "lime")
  draw(240, 60, 80, 30, angle * 0.7, "black", "cyan")
  draw(360, 80, 30, 70, angle * 2, "white", "black")
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    draw(440, 99, 30, 90, angle+i, "", "red")
  angle += 0.05
}

setInterval(loop, 100)
```

```html
<canvas height="180" width="600" id="c">
```

Comment: thanks for this, but I'm doing more than lines so preferring to clip within an elliptical region, using stroke, and not have the elliptical region stroked.

Comment: @SteveA this code is just a base to show you the math behind... you can draw the ellipse or not that is up to you